# MySQL concurrent read and write to one table

Tags: java, android, mysql, postgresql, relational-database

I know there are many topics regarding this but I do not feel they are as specific to my question. I'm currently working on my university dissertation - and am creating an Android application - one of the requirements is to be able to handle a large amount of users at one time, the example given was Instagram for example many thousands of people may be trying to view A celebrity picture on my application; I need to be able to load this image quickly for the end user, for all of them in a quick manner.

I coded the application using MySQL for the DB. Do you think this would be a problem? With large amounts of concurrent read and writes happening in the same place and table? If yes what is the possible solution.

I was reading about PostgreSQL being a lot better for this kind of thing, is that true? Also I have never used PostgreSQL because and if its advised to change to this how hard would it be to learn.

thanks

Comment: anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The way most companies fix this is by caching data on multiple servers. YouTube does this for its videos, once the video is uploaded to one server, it will share it with local server nodes which then they will share with other local nodes until the whole network has the data which distributed the loads over many servers. The problem this brings is keeping the data concurrent, obviously with a database, there will be many changes which you will have to keep track of across many nodes but depending on your storage needs, this may vary.

Comment: Would you recommend me using MySQL for the DB part then or PostgreSQL? and how hard would it be to provide concurrent server allocation of the file? And when a user clicks on the image how does it know which server to go to? does each server keep track of its current traffic? thanks

Comment: I've had no experience with PostgreSQL so I cant give you any information on that (From what I've read, MySQL is faster). As for the concurrency, there are many ways to achieve this. You could have a merging system with a central node where all sub nodes will send their changes to it and the central node will send each sub node an updated record sheet. This may not be the best way to do this in your case but I dont know exactly how much load you're expecting. As for knowing which server to go to, you would use a load balancer switch, this will poll the servers and distribute the requests.

Comment: Ah thanks alot this is the answer I was looking for!